# Differentiable points of mapping of $z \to x^4 + i(1-y)^4$ where $z = x+ iy$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I want to find when this mapping is differentiable.

I want to check necessary conditions with Cauchy-Riemann:

I get the following:

$u_x = 4x^3$, $v_x = 0$, $u_y = 0$ and $v_y = -4(1-y)^3$

Obviously $u_y = -v_x$ always but for $u_x = v_y$, I get:

$$4x^3 = -4(1-y)^3 $$
$$x^3 + (1-y)^3 = 0$$
$$(x + (1-y))(x^2 -x(1-y) + (1-y^2)) = 0$$
$$ x= y-1 \text{ or }  x = \frac{(1-y) \pm \sqrt{(1-y)^2 - 4(1-y)^2}}{2}$$
$$ x= y-1 \text{ or }  x = \frac{(1-y) \pm \sqrt{-3(1-y)^2}}{2}$$
$$ x= y-1 \text{ or }  x = \frac{(1-y) \pm \sqrt{3} i(1-y)}{2}$$
$$ x= y-1 \text{ or }  x = \frac{(1-y)(1 \pm \sqrt{3} i)}{2}$$

Is what I've done right and should I get 3 lines along which the mapping is differentiable?

Comment: The equation $x^3=(y-1)^3$ implies $x=y-1,$ because $a^3=b^3$ is equivalent to $a=b.$